# Vim ALE seems to be "ignoring" pyright

Tags: neovim, plugin-ale, plugin-python-mode

I'm having issues with setting up [`ale`](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) and [`pyright`](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/).

According to the documentation on both repos, everything should work out of the box, but that doesn't seem to be the case for me. I'm guessing it's another plugin causing issues, but I'm not sure.

The issue I have is that when I do `:ALEInfo`, I see "enabled" and "ignored" linters like this:

```
  Enabled Linters: ['flake8', 'mypy', 'pylint', 'pyright']
  Ignored Linters: ['pyright']
```

I tried using the "explicit" mode for ALE by doing something like this:

```
let g:ale_linters_explicit = 1
let g:ale_linters = {
      \ 'python': ['pyright', 'mypy'],
      \ }
```

But then, I'd still get:

```
  Enabled Linters: ['mypy', 'pyright']
  Ignored Linters: ['pyright']
```

So, I'm wondering why is `pyright` being ignored?